# Angular module doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, highcharts

I have this angular module I am using for a widget that displays a Highcharts chart, but for some reason it isn't displaying. I have the module name and the controller name but declared in the html, but I guess I am missing something?

```
angular.module('myapp', ['cgOwf'])
  .controller('mainctrl', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http, $interval, owf) {
        $scope.jsondata = [];
        var mainInterval = '';
        $scope.username = '';
        owf.ready(function() {
          owf.Eventing.subscribe('traffic-channel', function(sender, msg, channel) {
            console.debug("Got " + msg + " inside of owf ready");
            $scope.username = msg;
            console.log($scope.username);
            //-----------------------------------------------
            $scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
              chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'areaspline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                  load: function() {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random() * .5;
                      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 5000);
                  }
                }
              },
              title: {
                text: ''
              },
              xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
              },
              yAxis: {
                title: {
                  text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#d9534f'
                }]
              },
              tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
              },
              legend: {
                enabled: false
              },
              exporting: {
                enabled: false
              },
              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },
              series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                  // generate an array of random data
                  var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;
                  for (i = -10; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                      x: time + i * 1000,
                      y: Math.random() * .2
                    });
                  }
                  return data;
                }())
              }]
            });
          });
        });
      }
  }));
```

From the `//---------------------------` down it is really just setting up the chart, so i guess the part in question is above that. Here is the html, but this should be right because I've done this a few times:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainctrl">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div style="margin: 1em">
            <h4>Traffic <span ng-show="username"> for {{username}}</span></h4>

                <div id="container" class="barchart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="js/owf/owf-widget-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owf/owf-widget-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owf/angular-owf.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I would suggest commenting your code, and supplying a link to a jsfiddle, It will help you get quality responses.

Comment: I actually can't provide a link to jsfiddle in this case because I am using something called owf and I have the dependencies for that in the code so it wouldn't load at all in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console (browser developer tools) ? Do you use highcharts-ng ?

Comment: to add `dependencies` in jsfiddle (when using raw github files) you can use [rawgit](http://www.rawgit.com)'s service .. i've added these as `external resources` here for you as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/b9qq0usq/1/